# TASM/TLINK: Data in uninitialized FARDATA? segment gets written to executable

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

As I need a buffer for temporary storage of my program and I don't want it's bytes written to the .exe file, I thought I simply move the declaration from the **.DATA** to the **.FARDATA?** section. The buffer on it's own almost needs an entire segment so I've chosen FARDATA? instead of **DATA?** - as lots of other uninitialized data has to go there.
Well, after taking a look at the resulting .exe file, it appears the bytes are written to it anyhow!

So a minimal example like this:

```
.MODEL COMPACT
.STACK 100h

.DATA 
array         DB 1,2,3,4,5,6

.DATA?
otherData   DW ?

.FARDATA?
buffer     DB  64000 dup (?)

.CODE
Main:
    MOV     AH,0
    INT     16H

    MOV     AH,4ch  
    INT     21h

END Main
```

takes up around 64KB.

Of course I suspect it's the order the segments are written to the .exe file. Using the DOSSEG directive looked like a promising fix but TASM just ignores it.

Where's my logical fallacy?

## Update

Obviously the above code assembled using MASM instead of TASM gives the desired result. So it must be a flaw of TASM'S MASM mode.

Comment: The section for uninitialised data is `BSS` I believe.

Comment: The DATA? and FARDATA? simplified segment names are MASM's equivalent of the BSS section. I'm using TASM in MASM mode.

Comment: What version of TASM and TLINK are you using and what commands are you using to assemble and link? The files generated here aren't bloated to 64K in size. How big are the files generated that you are getting? I'm using TASM 2.51 and TLINK 2.0.

Comment: Oh my god - you're absolutely right Michael. I was invoking TLINK using a batch file and forgot that I added the /v command line switch (full symbolic debug information) there - without it, the file is around 1KB - as expected. Thanks for taking the time to test it and pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: No problem. I'd recommend adding the link command to your question and then you should self answer your own question with a solution.